# Extend $.Deferred.pipe() with a custom method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous

I want to extend $.Deferred.pipe with a custom method so I can shorten my deferred chain a bit.

The code I currently have is this

```
getDeferredFileEntry() 
//returns a ($.Deferred) promise to resolve with a FileEntry object
    .pipe(function(entry){
        //returns a promise to resolve with an object
        //containing the contents of the file as text
        //and a reference to the file's FileEntry
        var def = $.Deferred();
        entry.getDeferredText()
            .done(function(fileText){
                def.resolve({text:fileText, fileEntry:entry});
            });
        return def.promise();
    )}
    .done(function(response){
        var text = response.text;
        var fileEntry = response.fileEntry;

        console.log(text);
        //do something with the text
        console.log(fileEntry);
        //do something else with the file entry after finished reading from it
        //e.g. deleting with something like fileEntry.remove();
    });
```

I would like to shorten that to

```
getDeferredFileEntry()
    .read(
        //uses the FileEntry object resolved by getDeferredFileEntry
        //to call an asynchronous fileEntry.read() *in the background*
        //the contents are then passed to the callback taken from below
        //returns promise to resolve with the fileEntry object for chaining
        function callback(text){ 
            //do something with the text
            console.log(text);
        }
    ) 
    .remove(
        function(fileEntry){
            //library call to remove fileEntry that read() promised
        }
    )
```

I'm struggling with how to pass the FileEntry object resolved from `getDeferredFileEntry()` to the custom `read()` in the background. Any advice would be appreciated

Comment: How is getDeferredFileEntry defined? the promise object it is returning will need to be modified to add the additional read method, or you will have to add the new read method to all promise objects.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply create some helper methods that abstracts away your pipe logic?

```
function getFileEntry() {
   // Returns a promise resolved when your file entry is available
}

function getFileContents( entryPromise ) {
  return entryPromise.pipe(function( entry ) {
    return readFileEntry( entry );
  });
}

function readFileEntry( entry ) {
  var dfr = $.Deferred();

  // do whatever you have to do to read the file
  // then call dfr.resolve( fileContents );

  return dfr.promise();
}

function removeFileEntry( entry ) {
  var dfr = $.Deferred();

  // do whatever you have to do to remove the file
  // then call dfr.resolve();

  return dfr.promise();
}
```

Using those methods, your code should end up looking like this:

```
var fileEntry = getFileEntry();

readFileEntry( fileEntry ).then(function(contents) {
    // Do something with your file contents
    removeFileEntry( fileEntry );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the custom methods would help a lot, you still would need to respect the chaining (e.g. by maintaining an internal queue).

In your situation, nesting callbacks is the simplest thing:

```
getDeferredFileEntry().then(function(entry) {
    return entry.getDeferredText().then(function(text) {
    // after finished reading from it:
        console.log(txt); // do something with the read text
        console.log(fileEntry); // do something with the file entry
        return fileEntry.remove(); // e.g. deleting it
    });
});
```

In case you rather want to use the piping solution, you could simplify it to

```
.pipe(function(entry) {
    return entry.getDeferredText().pipe(function(fileText) {
        return {text:fileText, fileEntry:entry};
    });
})
```

…instead of manually building Deferreds.